# How to write firestore database security rule while not use firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to use the phone number and password authentication for the application. These type of authentication is not provided by firebase. So, normally create user collection and implement login signup flow.

Another thing is that I use phone number authentication for OTP send and verify. So user entry is available in the authentical list.

I get request.resource.data.userUid from request and check that this userUid exists in authentication list.

```
match /user/{docId} {
allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.resource.data.userUid))
}
```

Normally from any table we can check like this. But I not found any way to access authentication list.

Any way to write security rule as per my requirement or I need to change my authentication flow?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Firebase Authentication, then you can't use security rules to control access to specific users.  There is no other way to validate the identity of the individual making the request.  `request.auth` will always be null in this case.

In case you didn't know, Firebase Auth does provide [phone number authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).  You should be using this along with Cloud Firestore to implement security rules effectively.

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep using your current auth provider, and sign the authenticated users in to Firebase Authentication by creating a custom auth provider as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens. That way your user information from the existing auth system, can become available in the `request.auth` variable in your Firestore security rules.